# How to limit digits in 9 by 9 matrix Julia

Tags: julia, prettytable

How can I limit the digits of data matrix to 2 digits?

```
data = reshape([tuple(c[i], c2[i]) for i in eachindex(c, c2)], 9, 9)
#9×9 Matrix{Tuple{Real, Real}}:


hl = Highlighter((d,i,j)->d[i,j][1]*d[i,j][2] < 0, crayon"red")
pretty_table(data ; header = names, row_names= names , highlighters=hl)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of ways to do this:

1. You can use the round function:

data = round(data, 2)

2. You can use string formatting:

data = ["{0:.2f}".format(x) for x in data]

Answer (score 0):

You can use an anonymous function as a formatter, like this:

```
formatter = (v, i, j) -> round(v, digits=2);

hl = Highlighter((d,i,j)->di,j*d[i,j][2] < 0, crayon"red")

pretty_table(data; header=names, row_names=names , highlighters=hl, formatters=formatter)
```

I encourage you to read the [documentations](https://ronisbr.github.io/PrettyTables.jl/stable/man/formatters/) for further options.

Answer (score 0):

You can round the numbers when creating the `data` variable:

```
round2(n) = round(n; digits = 2)
data = reshape([tuple(round2(c[i]), round2(c2[i])) for i in eachindex(c, c2)], 9, 9)
```

Or if you want to maintain precision in the `data` array, but limit to 2 digits just for the printing, you can use the `formatters` keyword argument of PrettyTables:

```
pretty_table(data; header = titles, row_names = titles, formatters = (v, i, j) -> round.(v; digits = 2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand you have a matrix of tuples such as:

```
julia> mx = [tuple(rand(2)...) for i in 1:3,  j=1:2]
3×2 Matrix{Tuple{Float64, Float64}}:
 (0.617653, 0.0742714)  (0.0824311, 0.0344668)
 (0.327074, 0.235599)   (0.912262, 0.0250492)
 (0.116079, 0.387601)   (0.804606, 0.81485)
```

This can be rounded as:

```
julia> (x->round.(x;digits=2)).(mx)
3×2 Matrix{Tuple{Float64, Float64}}:
 (0.62, 0.07)  (0.08, 0.03)
 (0.33, 0.24)  (0.91, 0.03)
 (0.12, 0.39)  (0.8, 0.81)
```